# Is the double asterisk ** a valid JavaScript operator?

Tags: javascript, math, operators

I solved a kata on CodeWars and was looking through some of the other solutions when I came across the double asterisk to signify to the power of. I have done some research and can see that this is a valid operator in python but can see nothing about it in JavaScript documentation.

```
var findNb = m =>
{
  var n = Math.floor((4*m)**.25);
  var sum = x => (x*(x+1)/2)**2;
  return sum(n) == m ? n : -1;
}
```

Yet when I run this solution on CodeWars, it seems to work. I am wondering if this is new in ES6, although I have found nothing about it.

Comment: `**` is the markdown indicator for bold. It was likely a syntax error by the author when writing the markdown answer.

Comment: from [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-multiplicative-operators): _MultiplicativeOperator : one of
* / %_

Comment: @Grundy he's also using the fat arrow, so its possible

Comment: @r3wt, i not quite understand what you mean :-) link above to ES6 specification, where just three multiplicative operators

Comment: The [fat arrow (=>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is in the ES6 spec.  The [exponential operator (**)](https://github.com/rwaldron/exponentiation-operator) is in the ES7 spec.  I don't know anything about codewars, but this could be valid JavaScript if you were using [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) or [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: So, I just looked at codewars, all of their code runs through BabelJS, which explains why this code works with ES6 and ES7 operators.

Answer (score 92):

Yes. `**` is the **exponentiation operator** and is the equivalent of `Math.pow`.

It was introduced in ECMAScript 2016 (ES7).

For details, see the [proposal](https://github.com/rwaldron/exponentiation-operator) and this [chapter](https://leanpub.com/exploring-es2016-es2017/read#ch_exponentiation-operator) of *Exploring ES2016*.

Answer (score 30):

`**` was introduced in ECMAScript 2016 (ES7). But keep in mind that not all javascripts environments implements it (for instance, Internet Explorer does not support it).

If you want to be cross browser, you have to use `Math.pow`.

```
Math.pow(4, 5)
```

Comment: ^^^ indeed, it will throw `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *(…)`

Comment: This answer depends which ECMAScript version you are using, because it's wrong for ES7 as Thomas pointed out

Comment: This answer may have been correct when it was posted, but it is now incorrect. It should be edited to mention the JavaScript versions in which `**` does/does not exist.

Answer (score 7):

`**` operator is a valid operator in ES7. It holds the same meaning as `Math.pow(x,y)`
For example, `2**3` is same as `Math.pow(2,3)`

Here are the details from Wikipedia.

Two new features added in ES7:

> the exponentiation operator (**) and Array.prototype.includes

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#cite_ref-ES2016_12-1

You can play with this in this [Babel Live compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=console.log(2**3)%3B)