# Javascript double ** opertator in math

Tags: javascript, math, operators

can somebody explain me please what this line of code is actualy doing?

```
console.log(2 * 3 ** 4)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the double asterisk \*\* a valid JavaScript operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284569/is-the-double-asterisk-a-valid-javascript-operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `console.log(2 * 3 ** 4);` will produce the output: 162.

The ** works as exponent or power of the value. so 3**4 means `3x3x3x3 = 81`. So 2*81 becomes 162.